# Package 'libwxgtk3.0-dev' has no installation candidate on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

Trying to setup a development environment for opencpn on Ubuntu 20.04 (focal).

I get the following error message:

```
dave@nuc3:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake gettext git-core gpsd gpsd-clients libgps-dev wx-common libwxgtk3.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgtk2.0-dev wx3.0-headers libbz2-dev libtinyxml-dev libportaudio2 portaudio19-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat1-dev libcairo2-dev libarchive-dev liblzma-dev libexif-dev libelf-dev libsqlite3-dev
[sudo] password for dave: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'git' instead of 'git-core'
Package libwxgtk3.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwxgtk3.0-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone suggest how I might resolve the missing libwxgtk3.0-dev library?

Comment: Please **first** run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt full-upgrade`. If you see any messages, errors, or warnings, post the entire output of both commands here.

Comment: What was wrong [with simple](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=opencpn) `sudo apt-get install opencpn` ?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, I did that to start with but am unable to find OpenCPN plugins for Ubuntu focal so I need to compile the plugins myself, and so I have started with OpenCPN.

Comment: @user535733 That's it. I resolved it by substituting `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev` for `libwxgtk3.0-dev` in the list of packages to install. Everything compiled fine and I have been able to compile most of the plugins I want as well.

Answer (score 6):

`libwxgtk3.0-dev` was changed to `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev` in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: its actually libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev

Comment: @IgorSkoric yes, thank you, can someone fix the answer to this? So every doesnt have to use wrong one on first try?

Answer (score 2):

The package was renamed from `libwxgtk3.0-dev` to `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev` like @igor pointed out in the comments.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 20.10