# Trying to Install WoeUSB on 20.04, but Missing libwxgtk3.0-0v5?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, 20.04

I'm trying to install woeusb on Kubuntu 20.04LTS, but I seem to be missing a dependency. I have Universe and Multiverse enabled as sources, yet this still happens:

```
root@LesserArk:/home/sarah# apt install woeusb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 woeusb : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@LesserArk:/home/sarah# apt install libwxgtk3.0-0v5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libwxgtk3.0-0v5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwxgtk3.0-0v5' has no installation candidate
```

Here are my hardware stats:

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: LesserArk Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ENVY 17 Notebook PC v: 097E110000405E00000620100 
           serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1968 v: KBC Version 93.52 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Insyde v: F.70 
           date: 10/20/2017 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 41.2 Wh condition: 41.2/41.2 Wh (100%) model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-4702MQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell rev: 3 L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 35119 
           Speed: 2594 MHz min/max: 800/3200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2594 2: 2594 3: 2594 4: 2594 5: 2594 6: 2594 7: 2594 
           8: 2594 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nvidia v: 390.132 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~75Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.132 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-31-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: wlp7s0 state: up mac: e4:70:b8:f8:99:b8 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 0f:00.0 
           IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: a0:1d:48:fa:67:c0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 3.23 TiB used: 1.14 TiB (35.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABD100 size: 931.51 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: LITE-ON IT model: LMS-24L6M-HP size: 22.37 GiB 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Seagate model: ST2000LM015-2E8174 size: 1.82 TiB 
           ID-4: /dev/sdd vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 500GB size: 465.76 GiB 
           ID-5: /dev/sde type: USB vendor: Toshiba model: TransMemory size: 14.92 GiB 
           ID-6: /dev/sdf type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Gaming Xbox 360 size: 7.48 GiB 
           ID-7: /dev/sdg type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: U3 Cruzer Micro size: 1.91 GiB 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 bus ID: 00:1f.2 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 398.61 GiB used: 185.64 GiB (46.6%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sdd2 
           ID-2: /home size: 398.61 GiB used: 185.64 GiB (46.6%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sdd2 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 14.90 GiB used: 74.0 MiB (0.5%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdd3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 88.0 C mobo: 68.0 C gpu: nvidia temp: 65 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 470 Uptime: 1h 25m Memory: 15.57 GiB used: 9.21 GiB (59.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.16 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241217/package-libwxgtk3-0-dev-has-no-installation-candidate-on-ubuntu-20-04#comment2092252_1241217 helps.

Comment: @DKBose Nope, no luck. The -dev package didn't allow woeusb to be installed, and doing `apt update && full-upgrade` before didn't help either.

Comment: @N0rbert Wow! That actually worked! Not sure why, but it did! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it :)